# Boost.Python can't find pyconfig.h. Where does it need to go?

Tags: c++, python, import, shared-libraries, boost-python

I've written a very simple c++ function in main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int SomeCalculation(float x){
    int decision = 0;
    if (x > 1){
        decision = 1;
    }
    return decision;
}
```

I'm now trying to compile this as a shared library using Boost.Python. For this I created decision.cpp:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(decision)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("main", main);
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:8,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from decision.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error: pyconfig.h: File or folder does not exist.
compilation terminated.
```

Since I had no clue of where this file could be I did a simple `sudo find / -name pyconfig.h`, which found several pyconfig.h files. So I simply copied what to me seemed the most general version of the file, to the folder in which I'm working:

```
cp /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h /home/kram/c++/cmod/pyconfig.h
```

Running my compile command again (`g++ -fPIC -g -ggdb -c decision.cpp -o decision.so`) gives me the same error as before though.

Does anybody know how I can solve this pyconfig.h dependency?

[edit] Added pieces of code

Comment: AFAIK you should reference the correct headers and link to the python libs. This is done with `-lPython` and `-IPython` I think.

Answer (score 4):

Try command:

```
g++ -g -shared -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 decision.cpp -lpython2.7 -lboost_python -o decision.so
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That brings me a little bit further. I now get a new error. I've declared my function that I want imported (SomeCalculation()) in main.cpp and the boost.python wrapper is in the file decision.cpp. When I run the command you suggested I now get an error saying decision.cpp: In function ‘void init_module_decision()’: decision.cpp:6:17: error: ‘main’ was not declared in this scope. Would you have any clue of what's wrong here..?

Comment: @kramer65 I can not tell you what is the problem without that part of the code, where you use `main` in this function.

Comment: @Tsarloann - I added my code to my initial question. Does that give a clue of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @kramer65 You should change `def("main", main);` to `def("SomeCalculation", SomeCalculation);`.

Comment: @kramer65 I've done some testing and changed the compilation command a bit - now `decision.cpp` is mentioned BEFORE linker parameters. And that is important. Be attentive!

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Unfortunately that again gives me the same error: ‘SomeCalculation’ was not declared in this scope.. :S

Comment: @kramer65 You need to add declaration of `int SomeCalculation(float x)` somewhere and make it visible for `decision.cpp`. For example, put the following `int SomeCalculation(float x);` after line `#include <boost/python.hpp>`. Also add `main.cpp` to the compilation command.